# Everything works fine but i don't understand how it works?

Tags: java, android, operators

I made an app where i show all songs, albums, artists, genres and playlist.

I was reviewing my code for a bit because i got an error because i was checking if a String passed as a parameter was the same as a String inside my Album class getGenre() method which returns a String.

i resolved this error by changing

```
public ArrayList<Song> getSongsByGenre(String genreName) {

    ArrayList<Song> songsByGenre = new ArrayList<>();

  for (Song song : songs) {

        String currentSongGenre = song.getGenre();

        if (currentSongGenre.equals(genreName))
                songByGenre.add(song);
   }
}
```

**To**

```
public ArrayList<Song> getSongsByGenre(String genreName) {

    ArrayList<Song> songsByGenre = new ArrayList<>();

  for (Song song : songs) {

        String currentSongGenre = song.getGenre();

        if (Objects.equals(currentSongGenre, genreName))
            songsByGenre.add(song);
    }
}
```

What is the difference between Objects.equals and just currentSongGenre.equals(genreName); ?

Also what i don't understand is when i logged the values for '**currentSongGenre**' , '**genreName**' and the **if statement** in logcat.

```
Log.d(TAG, "value currentSongGenre: " + currentSongGenre);
Log.d(TAG, "value genreName: " + genreName);
Log.d(TAG, "value ifstat: " + currentSongGenre + " Equals " + genreName);
```

**Logcat debug**

```
SongList: value currentSongGenre: null
SongList: value genreName: Hip-Hop/Rap
SongList: value ifstat: null Equals Hip-Hop/Rap
```

So how does it work when both **String Values** are clearly not the same?

p.s this is how i set a genre, let me know if you need a more code because it's alot of code.

**I use 2 Hashmaps:**

songIdToGenreIdMap & genreIdToGenreNameMap, in the first one i add all song Id's and genre Id's found on the device and the second one i use to get the genre names.

```
String currentGenreID   = songIdToGenreIdMap.get(Long.toString(song.getId()));
String currentGenreName = genreIdToGenreNameMap.get(currentGenreID);
                    song.setGenre(currentGenreName);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first block you are not comparing to "genreName", but to "genre".

```
if (currentSongGenre.equals(genre))
```

Should be

```
if (currentSongGenre.equals(genreName))
```

Comment: But do you know what's the difference between .equals and Objects.equals?

Comment: Is it because currentSongGenre is null?  You can't call .equals on null, so that would give you a null pointer exception.  You could add a null check to resolve this ie if currentSongGenre != null && currentSongGenre.equals...

Comment: I don't think that there should be a difference, but Objects.equals would allow you to pass a null object, where you can not call .equals on a null object

Comment: But i don't understand how it returns the genres if currentSongGenre is null? Because in logcat currentSongGenre does indeed return null as you can see SongList: value ifstat: null Equals Hip-Hop/Rap?

Comment: And when i run my app it works fine, it returns a list of all song genres, but how does my if statement return true if currentSongGenre is null?